# How can I make a bot change it's presence (listening, watching, playing, etc...) displayed on discord under their name?

Tags: discord.py

I get nothing showing up that there is an error, but it does not show up in discord. Could someone show me what is wrong?

```
        async def change_status(self):

            await client.change_presence(game=Game(name = " ", type = 3))
```

I would like for the bot to have "listening" or "watching" show up on discord under it's name.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, Update:

(pretty sure this is rewrite)
I figure some people will look this up over time so here it is.

On the discord.py discord server I looked around through #help and found a place where it said the correct answers they just needed to be edited slightly. Here is the answer for it:

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="a game"))
```

This will set the bot to "Playing."

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="a movie"))
```

This will set it to "Watching" status.

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="a song"))
```

This will set it to a "Listening" status.

Answer (score 0):

You need the bot to specify when to change the status.
try @client.event this changes the status as the bot comes online.
to change listening to streaming or to watching try changing 2 ( 1,2,3,4 )
As far as i know to use the streaming status feature you need to link your twitch account with your code.

```py
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        await client.change_presence(game=Game(name='What ever in here',type = 2))
        print('Ready')
```